# Rotate the Rigidboy of player after mouse 3d project and create a text of timer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have my player controller script below , i want to ad a script in who can makes my player look at mouse (rotate all rigid body player to mouse without moving in front back , up/down 
what can i do ?

Also i have in my player controller a timer for when can player jump , I want to create a timer with UI TEXT , showing me how much time left (NextJumpTime) how can i convert to string or what i need to do whit it ? and if is possible to be more explicit .

```c#
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody PlayerRb;
    [SerializeField]
    float PlayerMoveSpped = 5f;
    [SerializeField]
    float PlayerJump = 3f;
    [SerializeField]
    private float JumpTimer = 5f;

    private float NextJumpTime;

    void Update()  //tot ce se intampla
    {
        Movement();
        if (ShouldJump())
                {
            Jump();
        }  // daca poate sari si mai jos sare
    }

    void Movement () //Miscari fata spate stanga dreapta
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            PlayerRb.AddForce(0, 0, -PlayerMoveSpped * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("s"))
        {
            PlayerRb.AddForce(0, 0, -PlayerMoveSpped * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            PlayerRb.AddForce(0, 0, PlayerMoveSpped * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("w"))
        {
            PlayerRb.AddForce(0, 0, PlayerMoveSpped * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            PlayerRb.AddForce(-PlayerMoveSpped * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
            PlayerRb.AddForce(-PlayerMoveSpped * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            PlayerRb.AddForce(PlayerMoveSpped * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            PlayerRb.AddForce(PlayerMoveSpped * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    private void Jump ()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            NextJumpTime = Time.time + JumpTimer;
            PlayerRb.AddForce(0, PlayerJump * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        }
    }  //script pentru sare

    private bool ShouldJump()
    {
        return Time.time > NextJumpTime;
    }  // masoara
}
```

Comment: Don't really understand what you mean but maybe this helps: https://answers.unity.com/questions/10615/rotate-objectweapon-towards-mouse-cursor-2d.html For the second question you can simply do `Text.text = String.Format("You have to wait {0:0.00} more seconds before you can jump again", NextJumpTime - Time.time` see http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/

Comment: Also why did you mix `GetKey("X")` with `GetKey(KeyCode.X)`? Would be cleaner to use `KeyCode` everywhere. And than you should combine your ifs like `if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))` instead of those separated if tags which are doing the same thing .. this might save some API calls and definitely some redundant lines of code